# Should users with 1 rep ask questions in an answer?

Tags: discussion

In this question [Error while launching TOR browser with Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39135108/error-while-launching-tor-browser-with-selenium-webdriver/39135187#39135187) a first time user posted an answer, but it really should be a comment.

However, first time users cannot comment, so should I down vote/flag the answer?  Or do I let it be.

**Edit:**
While my question is similar to [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer), it is different in that I am asking about how to handle users that post questions as answers **when they only have 1 rep**.  It has started significant discussion, so I don't think it should be closed.

Comment: Low rep is not an excuse for making a poor/bad answer. The answer should be flagged.

Comment: there is a flag called *"not an answer"* which does say *"This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, **a comment**, another question, or deleted altogether."*. Mods can turn answers into comments if they need to. ofcause in an perfect world new users should not really be doing this in the first place....but in a perfect world devs wouldn't need to try and break their own creations, emulating what dumb users would try and do (ie, inputting one's name in a price field or pressing the quick print button 100 times)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Being denied a privilege is not an excuse to violate the rules of the site to do what you want.  The question part is for the question, The answer section is for answers and the comments are for asking for clarification on either the question or answer.

If you see a question that is not a question then it needs to go.  Down vote it, flag/vote to close for the appropriate reason and possibly delete vote it(a lot of times this is unneeded as the [roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) will get it).

If you see a answer that is not an answer then it needs to go.  flag it is NAA/VLQ depending on the actual "answer".  Down vote it if it is not helpful to signal it is unhelpful and also allowing trusted users the ability to delete it.

One helpful thing to do would be to leave a comment on why the post is bad so that the user learns.  We want more users putting up more high quality content and the sooner they realize what the rules are and how the site works not only will they have a better experience but the site improves as well.  It doesn't take a whole lot to get 50 rep to be able to comment.  5 up votes on answers, 10 on questions or 25 approved edits will get you there.  The new users need to learn that we do have standards.

Answer (score 6):

As Memor-X mentioned in his answer posted as a comment - flag as **Not An Answer** in these specific cases. If you also additionally downvote is your own personal choice; from the perspective of moderation downvotes do matter. Quoting Louis in response to me earlier stating it is pointless in this case:

> Downvoting is not pointless. The downvotes are taken into account by
>   the rate-limiting algorithm even if the answer is deleted. Moreover,
>   if an answer has a negative score, people will 20k rep or more can
>   immediately cast delete votes on the answer.

You could casually drop a link to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) as a neutral way of attempting to educate said user; in my experience it doesn't really pay to try and explain it yourself, you'll likely just get deflective responses in the form of *"The site wouldn't let me comment"* or worse, and then you're stuck having to explain why new users can't comment, and so on.